# python loop folder/subfolder GetList() error

Tags: python, loops, directory

Trying to loop over folder/subfolder

```
file_list1 = drive.ListFile({'q': "'ID_of_drive' in parents"}).GetList()

for f1 in file_list1:
  file_list2 = drive.ListFile({'q': "'f1['id']' in parents"}).GetList()  # error!!!
```

I get an error:

> HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%27f1%5B%27id%27%5D%27+in+parents&maxResults=1000&alt=json returned "Invalid query". Details: "Invalid query">

If instead of

```
'f1['id']'
```

, I write a hardcopy of de the ID_of_drive, it works.

Comment: `f"'{f1['id']}' in parents"` ??

Comment: doesn't work...